# Getting a 500 error on simple html form POST

Tags: post, submit

My site has 2 pages, ask.php and ask_action.php.  I have an html form (on ask.php) that submits via jquery when the submit button is pressed.  It's action is `ask_action.php`  However, when i press the submit button, chrome is giving me a 500 error and this: `The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/s/ask_action.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.`  I'm also getting some weird behavior when i try to go back (to ask.php) or refresh. When i refresh, I also get a 500 error.  Then i refresh again and it works.  Sometimes there's a `#` appeneded on the end of ask.php in the URL.  This behavior is strange and I dont know what's causing it. Also, I do not have a .htaccess if that matters.

Contents of ask_action.php (for testing purpose):

```
<?php die("test"); ?>
 <html>...
</html>
```

ask.php form:

```
<form method='POST' action='ask_action.php' name='questionForm' id='questionForm'>

        <p><input type='text' name='Title' autocomplete='off' /></p>

        <p><textarea  name='Input'></textarea></p>

        <p><input type='text' name='topic' autocomplete='off' /></p>

        <p><input type='text' name='tags'  /> </p>
        <p><input type='button' value='submit' name='questionSubmit' id='questionSubmit' class='button2'></p>
</form>
```

I verified that ask.php and ask_action.php are in the same directory.

Comment: You have not provided enough of your code to comprehensively answer your question. The problem could very well be in your jQuery setup, or even the data you are sending.

Comment: @ranksrejoined jquery can't be the problem because the page is redirecting properly as noted in the error.  I will update my html for the form contents

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but still, did u try changing 
`<input type='button' to type='submit'`